# A crash at AFJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:data:error:

Tags: ios, afnetworking

```
Operating system: iOS
              8.3.0 12F70
CPU: arm64
 2 CPUs

Crash reason:  EXC_SOFTWARE / SIGABRT
Crash address: 0x193ea3270

Thread 35 (crashed)
 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib!__pthread_kill + 0x8
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  libsystem_pthread.dylib!pthread_kill + 0x6c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 2  libsystem_c.dylib!abort + 0x6c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 3  libsystem_malloc.dylib!nanozone_error + 0x13c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 4  libsystem_malloc.dylib!nano_realloc + 0x3fc
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 5  libsystem_malloc.dylib!malloc_zone_realloc + 0x78
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 6  CoreFoundation!__CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 0x518
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 7  CoreFoundation!CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation + 0x64
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 8  Foundation!-[NSPlaceholderString initWithData:encoding:] + 0x8c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 9  Mobile!-[AFJSONResponseSerializer     responseObjectForResponse:data:error:] [AFURLResponseSerialization.m : 253 + 0x10]
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
10  Mobile!__72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate     URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke69 [AFURLSessionManager.m : 179 + 0x1c]
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 11  libdispatch.dylib!_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 0x14
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
```

this crash was happened at iOS8.X,I don't know why,please help me resoulte this proplem,blow was crash stack,the lib of AFNetworking was 2.5.0,read code proplen happed at this line

```
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:stringEncoding];
```